# 'png_compression_level should be an integer from 0 to 9' upon uploading image

Tags: image

First time we see this: client tried to upload a specific PNG file (that a first sight looks ok) and Craft CMS returned the error 'png_compression_level should be an integer from 0 to 9'

[image: Error message]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This turned out to be [a bug](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/commit/8634b21f56d00a77c1e9db41816976bf95f1ed86) and the fix will be in the next release (current version is `3.5.15.1`).